# How to replace the DataField values with exact column names in Spark-MLlib PMML file?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

I use Spark 2.1.0.

I've been trying to export Spark-MLlib Linear Regression model as PMML file. I've also successfully exported the PMML file. But in that file, I couldn't see any field name in it. All I can see is like this,

[image]

Can anyone let me know what's the reason for this? Also, please let me know how to obtain the column names in place of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to exporting Apache Spark models into PMML data format. First, when working at Spark ML abstraction level, then you can use the [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library. Second, when working at Spark MLlib abstraction level, which appears to be the case here, then you can use the built-in `PMMLExportable` trait.

JPMML-SparkML retrieves column names from the Spark ML data schema via `DataFrame#schema()`. Unfortunately, there is no such option for Spark MLlib, so feature names "field_{n}" and the label name "target" are simply dummy hard-coded names.

It is fairly easy to rename fields in the PMML document using the [JPMML-Model](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-model) library:

```
pmmlExportable.toPMML("/tmp/raw-pmml-file")
org.dmg.pmml.PMML pmml = org.jpmml.model.JAXBUtil.unmarshal("/tmp/raw-pmml-file");
org.jpmml.model.visitors.FieldRenamer targetRenamer = new FieldRenamer(FieldName.create("target"), FieldRenamer.create("y"));
targetRenamer.applyTo(pmml);
org.jpmml.model.JAXBUtil.marshal(pmml, "/tmp/final-pmml-file");
```

If you marshal this PMML object instance to a PMML file, then you can see that the field "target" (and all its references) has been renamed to "y". Repeat the procedure with features.